# Email are going to Spam folder In Laravel

Tags: laravel, email, hosting, email-spam

I have a website that sends emails to users on creating an account and placing the order but all the emails are going to spam folder. The website is hosted with Inmotion hosting. I am working for a client, before that when the website is on my hosting the emails were going to inbox but not on inmotion hosting.
I have contacted the support and they said it is due to an authentication issue. Not sure what the issue.
I am also using SSL on the website. If anyone knows how to get rid of that please help me.

Comment: Run your emails through a spam scoring engine, check blacklists on sites like [https://mxtoolbox.com](https://mxtoolbox.com). Make sure the correct headers are present. Make sure the hosting companies servers aren't black listed.

Comment: may be your domain that you been used for your smtp is detected by email(gmail) that looks like a spam

Comment: There can be many different problems, this is a really broad topic. First ask Inmotion what they ment - they should help you. Second conduct forensics on your mx records, domain, SPF and your emails as @Ohgodwhy suggested. You can also use https://www.dnsstuff.com/ for that...

Answer (score 1):

It has nothing to do with laravel, you should use a good email-sending agent like mailgun.

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/emails-come-to-spam-folder